# Checking independence of A/B/C/... test results using Python

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, python, ab-test

Assume I collected the following results from an A/B/C/D/E test:

```
        Result 1    Result 2    Result 3
Control 21          7           32
VAR1    65          25          64
VAR2    107         50          94
VAR3    15          8           15
VAR4    189         6           2
```

The null hypothesis is that the results are independent and I want to use **Chi-Squared Test of Independence** [[1]](http://hamelg.blogspot.de/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-25-chi.html). To that end, I would like to use `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`.
However, in order to better understand the happenings, I reproduce the computations manually, as described in [1].

When taking the whole results set, everything works as expected; the `chi2` test statistic and the p-value computed manually or using  `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` are identical. This is also the case when taking subsets of the results (e.g. only two columns OR only two variations). I get puzzled once taking a 2x2 subset of the results (equivalent to a binary A/B test). Once doing so, the numbers that I get manually are no longer the same as those returned by `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`.

Here is a summary of the code behind my exercise:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import  stats


def comp_expected(df):
    """
    Compute the expected matrix
    """
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.outer(df.sum(axis=1), df.sum(axis=0)) / df.sum().sum(),
        columns=df.columns,
        index=df.index
    )


chi_squared_stat = lambda observed, expected: (((observed-expected)**2)/expected).sum().sum()
p_value = lambda observed, chi_squared_stat: 1 - stats.chi2.cdf(
    x=chi_squared_stat, 
    df=(observed.shape[0]-1)*(observed.shape[1]-1))

def compare_computations(observed):
    print(observed)
    chi2_stat = chi_squared_stat(observed, comp_expected(observed))
    pval = p_value(observed, chi_squared_stat(observed, comp_expected(observed)))
    chi2_contingency = stats.chi2_contingency(observed)
    print('chi2_stat = {}\npval = {}\nchi2_contingency output = {}'.format(
        chi2_stat, 
        pval,
        chi2_contingency
    ))
    print("chi2_stat identical - {}".format(np.isclose(chi2_stat, chi2_contingency[0])))
    print("pval      identical - {}".format(np.isclose(pval, chi2_contingency[1])))

# Observed data
observed_base = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Result 1": [21, 65, 107, 15, 189],
        "Result 2": [7, 25, 50, 8, 6],
        "Result 3": [32, 64, 94, 15, 2]
    },
    index=["Control", 
           "VAR1", 
           "VAR2", 
           "VAR3", 
           "VAR4"]
)
```

Now you can compare the results of `compare_computations(observed_base)` and `compare_computations(observed_base.iloc[0:2][observed_base.columns[0:2]])`. The full example can be found here [[2]](https://gist.github.com/drorata/f001d2f03812f4ca29c545e131e857d3/6154c7a6fdfa860bc0ccfce4087dd8d25de2957d).

## Question(s):

- Why in the latter case the "manual" computation does not yield the same results as the one provided by `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`?
- As far as I understand, if the returned p-value is smaller then 0.05, it means that the null hypothesis can be rejected with 95% certainty. Is that correct?
- What about the *statistical power* of the results? How can I compute it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is in the documentation of [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html). In particular, in case the number of degrees of freedom is `1`, then "Yates’ correction for continuity" is applied.

By replacing `stats.chi2_contingency(observed)` with `stats.chi2_contingency(observed, correction=False)` the results of the manual computation and the ones provided by `chi2_contingency` are always consistent.

I am still not sure about the other two questions. Now, in addition, I have to investigate what Yates' correction is.